# install drivers Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on MacBookPro

Tags: drivers, wireless, keyboard, mac, macbook

i was install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on MacBookPro 2018
but there are many things not working
like sound and wife and track-pad and keyboard
how can i install all of that
and also if write

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

is not work the output is

```
no drivers found for installation
```

Answer (score 0):

For wireless, it depends on the wireless driver you have. Mine is a BCM4322.  Here is what I did to get wireless working. If you run the command:

```
lspci
```

you'll get a long readout and at the very bottom it should list your network controllers. If you have Broadcom, the following should work.

First, you need to be connected.  I have ethernet, so I plugged it in.

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade  
sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

I had my setting page open and wireless popped up right after that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments.
In my case, not 'bcmvl-kernel-source' but 'bcmwl-kernel-source' was working.

'sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source'